# How to make a non-class type conform to a class protocol?

Tags: swift, mapkit, core-location

For example, how can I make MapView, which is a 'struct' type conform to CLLocationManagerDelegate which requires a 'class' type for its protocol?

```
Code Block 
struct  MapView: UIViewRepresentable, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
        MKMapView(frame: .zero)
    }
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: MKMapView, context: Context) {
        let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.0019, longitudeDelta: 0.0019)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinate, span: span)
        uiView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        uiView.mapType = .hybridFlyover
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't How about writing a class, and make that class a member of the struct?

Answer (score 1):

The protocol for CLLocationManagerDelegate has been set as type class, and it's made by apple. Thus we can't change it. Any reason you want to make it a struct rather than a class?

Comment: when I add the codes ```var showsUserLocation = true``` and ```MapView.showsUserLocation = true```  it gives me an error ```Instance member 'showsUserLocation' cannot be used on type 'MapView'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?``` . I was thinking I had to change MapView from Struct type to Class type/

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, you can't, but in this case it's particularly important why. Views are created and destroyed all the time; they're just values. A delegate is a specific object. There's no way for a View to play the role of a delegate. The CLLocationManager would wind having one copy, and you'd be looking at another copy in your view hierarchy. Instead, you need to create some other object, most likely an `ObservableObject` that tracks whatever location information you need, and the Views will observe that.